# EF Core with SQlite Database doesn't create table in MAUI App

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework, xamarin, maui

I just wanted to create a SQLite table in my MAUI app to holt some data, as I have used the same mechanism in a Xamarin app.
I am stuck now for many days, because the MAUI app wont close the database, as this is done in the Xamarin app.

Here is the code to describe the problem.

I included the Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore, the Microsoft.EntityFramework.SQLite.Core and also SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green. The NuGet Packages version is .NET 7.0.16.

In the MAUI app, I initialize the PCL batteries and create a transient for the database store.

```
   public static class MauiProgram
   {
       public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
       {
           SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init();
           var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
           builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                      fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                     fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });
           builder.Services.AddTransient<ISyncDataStore<PlaylistSyncItem>, SyncDataStore>();
           [...]
```

The database item is defined like this

```
public class PlaylistSyncItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int MP3ID { get; set; }

    public int Gefaellt { get; set; }

    public int GefaelltNicht { get; set; }

    public PlaylistSyncItem()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The store to connect the data is defined like this. Filehelper is the class to get the different paths on the platforms. I ommit the class.

```
public class SyncDataStore : ISyncDataStore<PlaylistSyncItem>
{
    public DbSet<PlaylistSyncItem> Items { get; set; }
    protected string DatabasePath { get; set; }

    private readonly IFileHelper _fileHelper;

    public SyncDataStore(IFileHelper fileHelper)
    {
        _fileHelper = fileHelper;
    }
    
    public async Task<bool> AddSyncItemAsync(PlaylistSyncItem item)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = CreateDbContext())
            {
                item.ID = 0;
                context.Items.Add(item);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                context.Database.CloseConnection(); // Add this line to manually close the connection
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
    private SyncDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var databasePath = _fileHelper.GetLocalDatabasePath("Playlist.db");
        return new SyncDbContext(databasePath);
    }
}

public class SyncDbContext : DbContext
{
    private string DatabasePath = null;
    public DbSet<PlaylistSyncItem> Items { get; set; }

    public SyncDbContext(string databasePath)
    {
        DatabasePath = databasePath;
        Database.EnsureCreated();
        Database.Migrate();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={DatabasePath}");
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()));
    }
}
```

The store will be instantiated by dependency injection in my MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private readonly ISyncDataStore<PlaylistSyncItem> _syncDataStore;

public MainPage(ISyncDataStore<PlaylistSyncItem> syncDataStore, IFileHelper fileHelper)
{
            _fileHelper = fileHelper;
            _syncDataStore = syncDataStore;
            [...]
```

I simply call the function by

```
await _syncDataStore.AddSyncItemAsync(item);
```

I did many tests, but it seems the database is just closed in rare cases, even if I close the app. It is more a random behavior. As this the only database class at the moment, I can't explain it by side effects in the app.

The database is filled by the data as expected:

INSERT INTO "Items" ("Gefaellt", "GefaelltNicht", "MP3ID")
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2)
RETURNING "ID";

There are no errors.

On the android device I have the files

- playlist.db
- playlist.db-shm
- playlist.db-wal

Am I tracking a ghost, as now Android cares itself for the closing of the database? I have no idea, but it is hard for me to debug anything.

I tried to switch to a DBContext not as baseclass, but as local object in a using clause. I expect the database to be closed after my commands (and also if the app is closed regular).

Comment: Your titles says the problem is that it does no create tables, but the post instead repeatedly mentions “closing”.  I have no idea what “closing” means in this context